# Android app for working with Kubernetes

Tags: android

Technically a small wrapper around `kubectl` functionality would suffice but anything that visually helps with administration of a Kubernetes cluster would be great.

I'm currently using JuiceSSH to ssh into my workstation and use `kubectl` from there but that's not quite ideal.